# What happens when I give strftime invalid specifier?

Tags: c

I tried to supply strftime the modifier %k which is not in the list, and it prints 11, what does strftime do, when I supply a modifier that is not in its list ?

Comment: My manual says that `%k` is the hour in 24-hour format, with a blank before single digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From  the  C standard of `strftime`:

> 6 If a conversion specifier is not one of the above, the behavior is
>   undefined.

You can see the [list of format specifiers](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strftime.html) for strftime. So what you are getting is an **undefined behavior**.

See the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) which says about %k

> **%k**     The hour (24-hour clock) as a decimal number (range 0 to 23);
>           single digits are preceded by a blank.  (See also %H.)  (TZ)

Answer (score 1):

> `%k`-
>     The hour as a decimal number, using a 24-hour clock like `%H`, but padded with blank (range  0 through 23).

But this format is a GNU extension. [See here listed specifiers](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatting-Calendar-Time.html).

And if the specifier not listed is used code will exbhit *undefined behaviour*.